# Resume failed svnrdump dump | svnadmin load

Tags: svn, version-control, svnadmin, svn-administraton

I tried to clone a remote svn repo like this:

```
svnadmin create /root/repo/
svnrdump dump svn://myserver | svnadmin load /root/repo/
```

But it failed with:

```
svnadmin: E140001: Sum of subblock sizes larger than total block content length
* adding path : [snip] ...svnrdump: E210008: Error while replaying commit
```

That doesn't look like a very meaningful error message.  Is there some way I can just resume the dump/load operation?

Comment: So, this doesn't work: `svnrdump dump svn://server/ -r REV:HEAD | svnadmin load /root/repo/` (where REV is the last revision to be loaded).

Answer (score 2):

You need to include --incremental something like

svnrdump dump svn://server/ --incremental -r REV:HEAD | svnadmin load /root/repo/